# Custom policy to deployIfNotExists for function app should have client certificates enabled

Tags: azure-policy

I am trying to remediate one of the defender for cloud recommendations i.e (Function apps should have Client Certificates (Incoming client certificates) enabled). I have just modified the effect of inbuilt policy as deployIfNotExists and trying to assign it on test machine but it is not working as expected. Can somebody help me know the custom policy for this use case.

```json
{
    "properties": {
      "displayName": "function app should have  client certificate",
      "policyType": "Custom",
      "mode": "All",
      "metadata": {
        "version": "1.0.1",
        "category": "App Service",
        "createdBy": "faa7d217-4419-499b-9d86-4cd7112f88ab",
        "createdOn": "2022-06-08T11:11:39.3281436Z",
        "updatedBy": "faa7d217-4419-499b-9d86-4cd7112f88ab",
        "updatedOn": "2022-06-08T11:21:58.3249668Z"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "effect": {
          "type": "String",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Effect",
            "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
          },
          "allowedValues": [
            "Audit",
            "Disabled",
            "DeployIfNotExists"
          ],
          "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
        }
      },
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
            },
            {
              "field": "kind",
              "like": "functionapp*"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/clientCertEnabled",
              "equals": "false"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
        }
      }
    },
    "id": "/subscriptions/a98b0a61-c76f-4334-afbc-33f49d7af1f7/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/4a8bbbc0-8f82-429b-ac84-527ba4c9fed4",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
    "name": "4a8bbbc0-8f82-429b-ac84-527ba4c9fed4",
    "systemData": {
      "createdBy": "maheshcg2@outlook.com",
      "createdByType": "User",
      "createdAt": "2022-06-08T11:11:39.303033Z",
      "lastModifiedBy": "maheshcg2@outlook.com",
      "lastModifiedByType": "User",
      "lastModifiedAt": "2022-06-08T11:21:58.2882516Z"
    }
  }
```

I guess I should have added deployment blocks, if yes can somebody help me here. I am getting the error below while trying to assign it on a test machine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this community policy, but it seems doesn't deploy the client certification on non-compliant resource.. Anybody has any idea on this..

{
"properties": {
"displayName": "function app should have  client certificate",
"policyType": "Custom",
"mode": "All",
"metadata": {
"version": "1.0.1",
"category": "App Service",
"createdBy": "faa7d217-4419-499b-9d86-4cd7112f88ab",
"createdOn": "2022-06-08T11:11:39.3281436Z",
"updatedBy": "faa7d217-4419-499b-9d86-4cd7112f88ab",
"updatedOn": "2022-06-08T16:45:35.511032Z"
},
"parameters": {
"effect": {
"type": "String",
"metadata": {
"displayName": "Effect",
"description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
},
"allowedValues": [
"DeployIfNotExists",
"Disabled"
],
"defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
}
},
"policyRule": {
"if": {
"allOf": [
{
"field": "type",
"equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
},
{
"field": "kind",
"like": "functionapp*"
},
]
},
"then": {
"effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
"details": {
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
"name": "[field('name')]",
"existenceCondition": {
"field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/clientCertEnabled",
"equals": true
},
"evaluationDelay": "AfterProvisioningSuccess",
"roleDefinitionIds": [
"/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/de139f84-1756-47ae-9be6-808fbbe84772"
],
"deployment": {
"properties": {
"mode": "incremental",
"parameters": {
"name": {
"value": "[field('name')]"
},
"location": {
"value": "[field('location')]"
}
},
"template": {
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"name": {
"type": "string"
},
"location": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"resources": [
{
"name": "[parameters('name')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
"apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
"properties": {
"clientCertEnabled": true
}
}
]
}
}
}
}
}
}
},
"id": "/subscriptions/a98b0a61-c76f-4334-afbc-33f49d7af1f7/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/4a8bbbc0-8f82-429b-ac84-527ba4c9fed4",
"type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
"name": "4a8bbbc0-8f82-429b-ac84-527ba4c9fed4",
"systemData": {
"createdByType": "User",
"createdAt": "2022-06-08T11:11:39.303033Z",
"lastModifiedByType": "User",
"lastModifiedAt": "2022-06-08T16:45:35.4899065Z"
}
}

It is able to identify the non-compliant resource however unable to remediate it.

Any inputs here please

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).